# returning an array within a row in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2012, asp.net-core-2.0

The following is a simplified version of my set up.

If i were to have a system that keeps track of the toys that children play with, my database would have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Children
Id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Name VARCHAR NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE Toys
Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
Name VARCHAR NOT NULL

CREATE TABLE Plays_With
Child_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
Toy_Id INT PRIMARY KEY,
CONSTRAINT FK_Child FOREIGN KEY Child_Id REFERENCES Children(Id),
CONSTRAINT FK_Toy FOREIGN KEY Toy_Id REFERENCES Toys(Id)
```

My C# classes would look like this:

```
public class Child 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public List<Toy> Toys {get; set;}
}

public class Toy 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

(Please ignore any syntax errors above as it's a description of the set up, not the actual code)

Now to the actual question, is there a way to retrieve the information necessary to fill a list of Child objects (retreiving every child and their associated toys) with a single stored procedure?

Comment: SQL 2012 cannot do JSON (you need SQL 2016 for that), but it can do XML.  So yes, you can write your query/procedure to return you the XML containing your children/toy lists, and parse that into your c# objects.  I don't believe anyone here is going to take this much further without you showing your work so far to obtain the results you need.

Comment: @DaveCullum it looks like xml is the way to go. what would my query look like if i wanted to generate something along the lines of: <child id=1 name='mike'><toy id=1 name='rubiks cube'></toy></child>

Comment: Basically it depends how what you are using in the c# code - I'm guessing different ORMs have different ways to handle such things, and it's going to be different if you want to use a DataSet or DataReader... Nonetheless it is possible in all the ways I've  listed, and of course also with XML as Date Cullum wrote.